# OkHttp RequestBody returning wrong content length

Tags: java, android, rest, okhttp

I have this app where I use [OkHttp RequestBody](http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/RequestBody.html) to perform network requests with body, but the content length being returned is plain wrong. As an example of the problem, there is this case:

```
    public static RequestBody createNewTokenBody(final String redirectUri, final String
        code,
                                             final String clientId, final String
                                                     clientSecret) {

    final byte[] requestBody = "bunchofcharsthatshouldgointhebody".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    final RequestBody ret = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(MEDIA_TYPE), requestBody, 0,
            requestBody.length);

    try {
        Log.d("debug", "Request body length to return: " + ret.contentLength());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

So this will print "Request body length to return : 33". **However**, when the request this body is attached to is captured by the interceptor below:

```
    client.networkInterceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(final Chain chain) throws IOException {
            final Request request = chain.request();

            final RequestBody body = request.body();
            if (body != null) {
                Log.d("debug", "REQUEST BODY LENGTH: " + body.contentLength());
            }

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });
```

"REQUEST BODY LENGTH: 2" **is logged instead, regardless of the content that I specified**. Needless to mention that this completely screws up the request as the body is not fully read. Does anybody know the reason behind this behavior?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Should it be needed for future reference, this was reported as a bug in Retrofit-2 beta1 and is already fixed in the current snapshot.

https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1097

Comment: i am steel getting -1...i am using  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce this in a standalone test case. If you can, please report a bug against OkHttp with a minimal executable test case that demonstrates the problem.